# Ruby on Rails: is there an ideal app directory structure in Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Just a quick question from a Rails learner.
As I understand it, it is not necessary to place a new Rails app inside the directory where Ruby and Rails are installed.
But, is there an ideal place for apps? What are experienced developers using?

I ask this, because I may have misplaced a previous app, hidden somewhere deep in a directory structure; and, strange as it might seem to most of you, I cannot find where the older app is.
I have quite some problems searching in Windows 10; it is a nightmare, compared to how it was in Windows XP.

Comment: desktop, documents? wherever that's obvious I guess? or just put up an ubuntu vm

Comment: Use windows search: Search for 'Gemfile' to find your old app, and get rid of win10!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't "standard", community agreed directory structure for Rails apps.

However, I noticed that many developers would create `Projects` folder within their "user home" directory (`C:\Users\username` in Windows and `~` in linux distro). I do the same and when I need to find some project I worked on 5 years ago, I don't think twice where to look for it. Obviously, that means you'd end up with a lot of project dirs in your `Projects` folder. So I move very old projects to my backup disk occasionally.

A quick note on Ruby/Rails. Rails projects are not like PHP. They are more like Java, when you run your application (as a separate process) and it stays in the memory running & serving user requests. In PHP you had to put your php files into your server's document directory so that server could parse and execute your scripts. So, with Rails projects you are not limited with where you put them.